# How to test if React state is reloaded from localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, local-storage

I used Jest and Enzyme to test the component and I ran into a problem with reloading. I want my component to retrieve the state from the localStorage. I didn't implement the code yet but the test still pass.

```
  it('can preserve todo group', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<TodosContainer />);
    wrapper.find('input[name="todo-container-form"]').simulate('change', { target: { value: 'Loy' } });
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
    window.location.reload();
    /* This is where it should fail without implementation
    I didn't add any localStorage code in my component. */
    expect(wrapper.find(TodosGroup).first().prop('name')).toMatch('Loy');
  });
```

This is my component with irrevalent part redacted.

```
const TodosContainer = () => {
  const [todosGroups, setTodosGroups] = useState([]);
  const [groupName, setGroupName] = useState('');
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');
  const addTodoGroups = (todoGroup: ITodoGroup) => {
    setTodosGroups([...todosGroups, todoGroup]);
  };
  const changeName = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setGroupName(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (groupName.length > 0) {
      addTodoGroups({ name: groupName, key: Date.now() });
      setGroupName('');
      setErrorMessage('');
    } else {
      setErrorMessage('Group name must not be empty');
    }
  };
  return (
    <div    >
      <div      >
        {errorMessage.length > 0 ? <ErrorMessage css={css`width: 100%`}>{errorMessage}</ErrorMessage> : ''}
        <TextInput name="todo-container-form" className="todoGroupName" value={groupName} onChange={changeName} />
        <Button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>Add</Button>
      </div>
      {todosGroups.length > 0 ? todosGroups.map((todoGroup) => (
        <div
          key={todoGroup.key}
        >
          <TodosGroup name={todoGroup.name} />
        </div>
      )) : (
        <p>
        No todos group
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  );

};

export default TodosContainer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since jest uses JSDom instead of real browser `window.location.reload();` does nothing. Also I'm afraid jsdom does not implement `localStorage` either(but it's easy [to mock that](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/1137))

You want to ensure that after component is recreated it takes state from localstorage, right?

This way(after appropriate mocking `localStorage`) you may just [unmount](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/unmount.html) component and mount it again:

```
wrapper.unmount();
const newOne = mount(<TodosContainer />);
expect(newOne.find(TodosGroup).first().prop('name')).toMatch('Loy');
```

Explicit unmounting *is not* required here, but I'd rather have it to simulate conditions completely(say, it would run `componentWillUnmount`/`useEffect` that may be part of logic).